# include variable in another variable in bash

Tags: bash

I am writing a loop in bash where I want to include one variable in another variable:

```
  printf "Number of volumes to add: "
  read -r num_volumes
  for volume_number in "$num_volumes"
  do
    vol_id_{$volume_number}="create_volume"
  done
```

Is this the correct syntax to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, when ever you're tempted to use variables like `foo_1`, `foo_2`, etc., just don't. Use an [array](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays) instead:

```
foo=()
foo[0]=123; foo[1]=456;
printf "%s\n" "${foo[@]}"
```

Or, if you need non-numeric keys, [an associative array](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Associative_Arrays):

```
declare -A bar=()
bar[abc]=123; bar[def]=456;
for key in "${!bar[@]}"; do echo "$key: ${bar[$key]}"; done
```

---

As for your code, `for volume_number in "$num_volumes"` will run the loop body once, with `volume_number` set to the contents of `num_volumes`. The quotes prevent any splitting of `num_volumes` so there's only one word for `for` to loop over. Given that your prompt and variable name refer to a number of something, you probably don't even want to split, but to loop over a list of numbers:

```
read num
vars=()
for (( i=0; i < num; i++ )); do
    vars[i]="some value for $i"
done
```